# Azure preview portal wont let me import a database from bacpack

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac, azureportal

I'm trying to import a database from a bacpack. Done this many times before without issue, but now it won't work and doesn't give any indication of the problem, just mocks me with a blank messagebox.. [image: blank message box]. 
How can I troubleshoot this? I've made sure of the obvious..
1. 24 databases on my server with lots of DTUS left in my quoata.
2. The name is unique.

Comment: Hello, I work for Microsoft on the SQL Azure team. Could you send some information regarding the issue to my email? If you could send you subscription ID, the server name which you are trying to import into, and the rough time/timezone at which you were attempting to do this, it would be very helpful. My email is elfish at Microsoft dot com.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on this and decided to use SqlPackage.exe to have more control over the import process.  Thanks!